# Why is there white space after my inline-block?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float, whitespace

I'm using the float style to remove white spaces and I want to center it, but another white space appears after my `div#bar`

[image]

This is my html:

```
<div id="foo">
    <div id="bar">
        <div class="divo divo1">test1</div>
        <div class="divo divo2">test2</div>
        <div class="divo divo3">test3</div>
        <div class="divo divo4">test4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#foo {
    width: 100%;
    background: #999;
    text-align: center;
}
#bar {
    display: inline-block;
}
.divo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kodam/ay3ywtqa/

Note: I don't want to use negative margin or font-size 0 styles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since #bar is an inline element, it has space reserved for descender text elements (e.g. j, y, g). You could float that left, but that would collapse it, so I'd recommend setting the vertical alignment to top:

```
#bar {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ay3ywtqa/4/)**

Comment: It looks like `vertical-align` is by default `vertical-align: baseline;`. Thus when we change something to `display:inline-block`, our object is displayed vertically aligned to base, and we have to set it to `top` (or wherever) depending...this seems like something simple but took me a long time to remember to get to stick in my head! Frustrating when things aren't lining up right!

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
   #foo {
        width: 100%;
        background: #999;
        font-size:0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #bar {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size:13px;
    }
```

set parent font-size to 0, then set the needed font-size to the children.

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ay3ywtqa/3/

Comment: It works but I dont want to use font-size style bro

Comment: @DocKodam you should :p